# Best way for Retrieving data from more tables in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to laravel and I have a simple question, I am writing the controllers for my application and i need to do one simple things, i have to return a model with data from more tables, how would you do this?
for example: i need to return to the view a 'Comment' with the name of the 'User' that wrote the comment but the model 'Comment' has only the id of the 'User' in 'id_user', how do i return the comment with the name of the user?

Comment: you need to join the tables together in your query

Comment: write code for join multiple tabels. here is doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins

Comment: Set up your model relations, then https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: Thats a good question. To 1 result its easy with joins. But if we select many records its not that easy I think. To solve this, I use foreach() and for every result I translate the field id into name. Someone help ?

Comment: hey guys thanks for the help, really appreciated... reading the documentation from your links i found this that's seems a really good solution even for performance https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: What have you tried so far? If your relations are setup properly, you could simply use something like `$comment->getUser()->getName()`

Comment: @NicoHaase yeah but i was searching for a way where i was sure that for 'n' models i wasn't executing one different query for every model, eager loading was the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the relationship between comment and user models,

I suggest you learning relationship first (in your case every user can have many comments)

Then you can use [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship

Then use 'With' and get every user with comments,

For instance :

```
$users = App\User::with('comment')->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {

   echo $user->comments->description;

}
```

Hope to help